# Car Wash Queue Issue

Tags: c++, queue

I'm working on a variation of the "Car Queue" or "Car Wash" problem in which I have to input how long a car will take to wash, the odds of a car entering the queue for the wash at any given moment, and then receive as output how many cars were washed, how many cars were left in the queue at the end of the day, and how much total waiting time there was. I'm still very new to c++, and have only been using it extensively for the last few months. Its very possible there's an error with my queue implementation code that I didn't catch, but I believe the error is in the main. Currently, I added outputs for every loop, so I could watch the code run, and follow it. It appeared to be accepting a car, and then immediately finishing the wash on it. Then, when no car is present, it simply alternates between a washing and waiting loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <assert>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Node
  {
    private:
     int item;
Node * next;
public:
    Node ();
    Node (const int& anItem);
    Node (const int& anItem, Node * nextNodePtr);
    void setItem (const int& anItem);
    void setNext (Node * nextNodePtr);
    int getItem ();
    Node* getNext();
   };
class LinkedQueue 
  { 
    private:  
       Node* backPtr; 
       Node* frontPtr; 
    public: 
       bool isEmpty(); 
       bool enqueue(int& newEntry); 
       bool dequeue(); 
       int peekFront() const;
       LinkedQueue();
       ~LinkedQueue();
       LinkedQueue(const LinkedQueue& aQueue); 
   };
int main ()
{   
    srand(1);
    int timeForWash;
    int minute;
    int timeEnteredQueue;
    int carsWashed;
    int totalQueueMin;
    int timeLeftOnCar;
    int probOfArrival;
    int carsInQueue = 0;

    LinkedQueue carQueue;

    cout << "Enter time to wash one car:" << endl;
    cin >> timeForWash;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter probability of arrival per minute" << endl;
    cin >> probOfArrival;

    carsWashed = 0;
    totalQueueMin = 0;
    timeLeftOnCar = 0;
    for (minute = 1; minute <= 20; ++minute)
    {
        if (rand()%100 <= probOfArrival)
            {
                carQueue.enqueue(minute);
                carsInQueue++;
                cout << "Queued" << endl;
            }

        if ((timeLeftOnCar == 0) && ( !carQueue.isEmpty()))
        {
            timeEnteredQueue = carQueue.peekFront();
            carQueue.dequeue();
            totalQueueMin = totalQueueMin + (minute - timeEnteredQueue);
            ++carsWashed;
            carsInQueue--;
            timeLeftOnCar = timeForWash;
            cout << "Finish" << endl;
            }
            if (timeLeftOnCar =! 0)
            {
                timeLeftOnCar -= 1;
                cout << "Washing" << endl;
            }
        if ((timeLeftOnCar == 0) && ( carQueue.isEmpty()))
        {
            cout << "Waiting" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << carsWashed << endl;
    cout << totalQueueMin << endl;
    cout << carsInQueue << endl;
    system("pause");
    return(0);
  };
//Implementation
Node:: Node() : next (nullptr)
{
} // default
Node:: Node (const int& anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr)
{
}

Node:: Node (const int& anItem, Node * nextNodePtr) : item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr)
{
}

void Node:: setItem (const int& anItem)
{
    item = anItem;
}

void Node:: setNext (Node * nextNodePtr)
{
    next = nextNodePtr;
}

int Node:: getItem ()
{
    return item;
}

Node * Node:: getNext ()
{
    return next;
}

bool LinkedQueue::enqueue(int& newEntry) 
    { 
     Node* newNodePtr = new Node(newEntry); 
     //Insert the new node 
     if (isEmpty()) 
     frontPtr = newNodePtr; // The queue was empty 
     else
     backPtr->setNext(newNodePtr); // The queue was not empty 
     backPtr = newNodePtr; // New node is at back 
     return true; 
} // end enqueue
bool LinkedQueue::dequeue() 
{ 
    bool result = false; 
    if (!isEmpty()) 
     { 
     // Queue is not empty; remove front 
     Node* nodeToDeletePtr = frontPtr; 
     if (frontPtr == backPtr) 
     { // Special case: one node in queue 
     frontPtr = nullptr; 
     backPtr = nullptr; 
     } 
     else
     frontPtr = frontPtr->getNext(); 
     // Return deleted node to system 
     nodeToDeletePtr->setNext( nullptr); 
     delete nodeToDeletePtr; 
     nodeToDeletePtr = nullptr; 
     result = true; 
     } // end if 
     return result; 
} // end dequeue
bool LinkedQueue:: isEmpty()
{
    return (frontPtr == nullptr );
}
int LinkedQueue:: peekFront() const
{
    return frontPtr->getItem();
} 
LinkedQueue::LinkedQueue() 
{
    frontPtr = nullptr;
    backPtr = nullptr;
} 
LinkedQueue::LinkedQueue( const LinkedQueue& aQueue) : 
frontPtr(aQueue.frontPtr) 
{ 
} // end copy constructor  
LinkedQueue::~LinkedQueue() 
{ 
} // end destructor
```

Answer (score 2):

`timeLeftOnCar =! 0` is the same as `timeLeftOnCar = !0`, which is `timeLeftOnCar = 1`, which is always true.

You want`timeLeftOnCar != 0` or `timeLeftOnCar > 0`.

Comment: Sigh. Its always the littlest things. Thank you very much. Seems to have cleared it right up. Running several tests to be sure

Comment: @Drew I recommend that you increase the warning level on your compiler. It's a great help against things like this (they're almost impossible to spot in your own code).